# How to implement a shortest path algorithm to find shortest route between any two given cities of a graph in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have an input file of the form :

```
    London Birmingham 117
    Birmingham Bristol 85
    London Oxford 56
    San_Francisco San_Jose 50
    San_Jose Davis 270
    San_Francisco Davis 350
    END OF INPUT
```

(Actual file has more number of nodes)I have to find a shortest path between two input cities (command line arguments) using an uninformed search algorithm.
Made a graph(list) so far by the following:

```
   Graph = {}
   filename = open('Input1.txt', 'r')
   for line in filename:

       node1, node2, d = line.split()
       Graph.setdefault(node1, []).append((node2, d))
       Graph.setdefault(node2, []).append((node1, d))  # Undirected graph

   """splitLine = line.split()
        Graph[(splitLine[0])] = " ".join(splitLine[1:])"""

  def generate_edges(Graph):
  edges = []
  for node in Graph:
    for neighbour in Graph[node]:
        edges.append((node, neighbour))

    return edges
  print(generate_edges(Graph))
```

It gives me output like :
[(London, (Birmingham,117)), (London,(Oxford,56)),(Birmingham,(London,117)),etc...]

As I am completely new to python and programming as such , I want to know what should be the next step or next function I should write and how to map the logic into implementation.

Comment: This is called the Traveling Salesman Problem. It is unsolved in the general case; a great deal of research goes into more or less usable approximations. The subject is therefore easily enough for multiple PhDs, which makes it entirely unsuitable for an SO question to try to cover.

Comment: I think the question asks for pair to pair shortest path, not a traveling salesman problem.

Comment: Wrong. The Traveling Salesman Problem asks for a path of shortest length through ALL nodes. It's an "NP-complete" problem, for which no efficient algorithm is known that works in all cases, though as you note correctly efficient approximations exists.

Comment: (cont) Reblochon Masque's answer below is correct: this calls for Dijkstra's algorithm (as all the edge weights are nonnegative), which is quite efficient. The wikipedia article gives pseudocode that can be massaged into working Python without much difficulty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm. You can use the heapq module for a priority queue, though you may find it necessary to subclass & extend it (I did, when implementing Dijkstra's algorithm: iirc, there's no "reheapify subtree at node n" method).

Comment: Finally, since you're new to both Python and programming, simply search for "Python Dijkstra": you'll find many published implementations, and even some tutorials with visualizations of how the algorithm works.

Comment: Fine point: The "verifying" version of Traveling Salesman is NP-complete, but the problem of finding a shortest circuit is actually **NP-hard** -- like NP-complete problems, any NP problem can be reduced to it; but it itself might not even be in NP (it might be harder still, perhaps inherently exponential in the worst case).

Answer (score 3):

This is single source shortest path (all pairs) algorithm with no negative edges (distance).

The most famous is [DIJKSTRA](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/)'s algorithm, but there are others like [PRIM](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-mst-for-adjacency-list-representation/)'s.

If you have negative edges, use Bellman-Ford-Moore